# Combine two column into one using EKL Stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

Hi i have **csv file** having following data:- [My CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skpkb.png)
Basically i want those records from csv file that only **Asserted** but not **Cleared** from **Alert column** I have highlighted in csv file.

> If you see in **Alert** column **HD** of Record20,**C2** of Record14 and **L1**
>   of Record21 columns are only **ASSERTED** But not **CLEARED**.

So I want those records whose Alert are Asserted but not Cleared using EKL Stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [elapsed filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elapsed.html) to match up records, which will also show you which ones are not matched.

Specifically to your example, you could split the Alert column into two: one with the "item" (e.g. H1, HG) and the other with the "action" (e.g. Asserted, Cleared).  Set the filter's `start_tag` as "Asserted" and `end_tag` as "Cleared" and use the new "item" as the `unique_id_field`.

Items that match will have new fields added.  If you gather the set of "Asserted" "H1", and remove the elapsed "Cleared" "H1", you'll find any stragglers.

Comment: :- Can please give some example..?